# Force specific outbound IP for specific ASN

Tags: iptables

In Linux (CentOS) how am I able to force the IP address 1.1.1.1 to be used for all outbound traffic on ASN # AS33522

Comment: Do you own the address `1.1.1.1`? No? Don't use deliberately just some random addresses as placeholders. Use only your own, private or specific addresses reserved for documentation purposes, e.g. `192.0.2.x`.

Answer (score 1):

This ASN is cPanel, which exposes two prefixes:

```
184.94.192.0/20
208.74.120.0/21
```

If an address `192.0.2.111` is assigned to `eth0` and the gateway behind that interface is `192.0.2.1`, you may add following routes:

```
ip route add 184.94.192.0/20 via 192.0.2.1 src 192.0.2.111
ip route add 208.74.120.0/21 via 192.0.2.1 src 192.0.2.111
```

And if the process which tries to reach those networks isn't already bound to some other IP address, it will use the hinted address specified in the `src` attribute of the route.

This will only leave these routes until reboot. To make changes permanent, run the on boot (e.g. put these commands verbatim into `/etc/rc.local`) or edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0` and add these routes there (omit `ip route add`).

---

I understand the desire to automate this in case they will buy and expose additional networks. Unfortunately, if you don't have any BGP peering with so called "full view", you won't get notified about this change and you are out of luxury to designate something "by ASN". ASNs are only for BGP, sorry.